# Cannot replace None values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace, nonetype

I have a pandas dataframe. It has some None values. I am trying to replace them with an empty string. Here is the code that I have written already.

```
data = pd.read_csv("./Drugs/drugsComTrain_raw.csv", skipinitialspace = True)
data["condition"] = data["condition"].fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
data["condition"] = data["condition"].replace(np.nan, "Empty", inplace=True)
```

But it is not happening. Because when I try to fit the data into a vectorizer it seems the None value is stille there. Below is the given the code where I am getting the error

```
def preprocess_text(text):
    print(f"text: {text}")
    print(f"type: {type(text)}")
    tokeniser = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokens = tokeniser.tokenize(text)

    lemmatiser = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmas = [lemmatiser.lemmatize(token.lower(), pos='v') for token in tokens]

    keywords= [lemma for lemma in lemmas if lemma not in stopwords.words('english')]
    return keywords

vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=preprocess_text)
condition = pd.DataFrame(vectoriser.fit_transform(data["condition"]).toarray())
```

Here is the error I am getting.

[image]

Comment: What is the dtype of the `condition` column?

Comment: dtype of the condition column is object

Comment: Just a thought; have you tried removing the `regex` parameter from this call: `data["condition"] = data["condition"].replace(np.nan, "Empty", inplace=True, regex=True)`?  Because `np.nan` is not a regex pattern.  Otherwise, I believe this should work ...

Comment: Yes. Still the same.